What physical properties give rise to abelian anyons as opposed to non-abelian anyons?
As far as I understand, abelian anyons are those which have a particle exchange operator which is a one-dimensional representation of the braid group.  Non-abelian anyons, then, have a higher-dimensional operator which, in general, does not commute.
What kind of physical considerations affect the dimension of the exchange operator?  I've been trying to understand why, despite both being confined to two-dimensional space, abelian and non-abelian anyons have different dimensional operators.

What do you mean by "physical considerations" here? There isn't exactly a long list of actual physical anyonic systems we could look at to determine some shared physical properties

Things like the number of degrees of freedom, degeneracy of states, or differences in the Hamiltonians are what I had in mind when I asked.
